# Dimensions don't match after changin data representation " LabelBinarizer "

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras, image-preprocessing

l have 66 classes of characters. l trained a multi layer perceptron feeding it with images and the class of each image is a character

> Aa..Zz 0-9 ,;:! è à â ~

l applied a `LabelBinarizer` to transform each character to a vector of 66 classes, (e.g.`[0 0 0  0 ....1 ...... 0]`) because  models don't accept non numerical data.
l was surprised to get dimension 61 for `y_test` (wrong) an `y_train` (66 correct).
what's wrong with my code ?

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_pixels, classes_dataset, test_size=0.3)
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print(x_test)
print("my y_train")
print(y_train[0:100])
print("my y_test ")
print(y_test[0:100])
```

**

```
(1708, 3072) # x_train shape
(1708,) # y_train shape
(732, 3072) #x_test shape
(732,) y_train shape
```

**

## x_test

```
[[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]]
```

**y_train**

```
 ['5' 'O' '9' '0' 'E' 'D' '9' ',' 'R' 'H' 'T' 'i' '\xc3\xa9' 'T' 'o' 'u' 'R'
     '2' '0' 'L' 'o' '0' '6' 'q' 'P' '6' '2' 'T' '2' '0' 'i' '0' 'f' 'A' 'r'
     'n' 'T' 'O' '8' 'B' 'T' 'd' '0' 'V' 'X' '9' '.' '6' 'J' 'S' 'E' 'O' 'T'
     '4' 'E' '0' 'I' '3' 'o' 'E' '6' 'R' 'M' '0' 'E' '1' 'R' 'T' 'E' '.' '0'
     'G' 'R' 'E' 'E' '0' '9' 'd' '1' '7' 'A' 'B' 'L' '4' 'l' 'O' '1' 'v' '3'
     '%' 'd' '0' 'T' 's' 'A' '6' 'w' 'slash' '2' '9']
```

**y_test**

```
['N' '0' 'F' '4' 'U' 'C' 'u' 'e' '0' ',' 'G' 'C' 'T' '%' '-' 'V' '5' 'P'
 'N' 'S' '8' '4' ',' 'm' '5' '3' 'e' 'I' 'i' 'M' 'I' '3' 'C' 'F' 'e' 'a'
 '6' 'R' 'V' '4' '0' 'f' '9' 'E' '2' '0' 'E' 'N' 'I' '5' '0' 'A' '%' '-'
 'G' '0' ',' 'O' 'Y' '\xc3\x89' 'R' 's' ',' 'A' 'I' '3' 'S' '2' 'P' '.' 'I'
 ',' 'r' 'I' 'i' '5' '5' 'R' 'C' 'e' '2' 'q' '.' 'R' 'O' 'n' 'S' '6' 'G'
 '0' 'R' 'i' 't' 'i' '9' 'I' 'D' 'slash' '0' 'A']
```

when l apply `LabelBinazer` l get `y_test` dimension `(732,61)` rather than `(732,66)`
66 means the number of classes :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test= encoder.fit_transform(y_test)

print(y_train.shape)

print(y_test.shape)
```

(1708, 66)

**(732, 61)** # **How come l get 61 rather than 66**

```
   **Edit**
```

After making changes as suggested

```
    y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)
l got the following error :
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-b554d33049ab> in <module>()
      1 y_said=encoder.fit(y_train)
      2 y_said
----> 3 y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.pyc in transform(self, y)
    333                               pos_label=self.pos_label,
    334                               neg_label=self.neg_label,
--> 335                               sparse_output=self.sparse_output)
    336 
    337     def inverse_transform(self, Y, threshold=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.pyc in label_binarize(y, classes, neg_label, pos_label, sparse_output)
    492     if (y_type == "multilabel-indicator" and classes.size != y.shape[1]):
    493         raise ValueError("classes {0} missmatch with the labels {1}"
--> 494                          "found in the data".format(classes, unique_labels(y)))
    495 
    496     if y_type in ("binary", "multiclass"):

ValueError: classes [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65] missmatch with the labels [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60]found in the data
```

**EDIT2 :**

```
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(y_train + y_test)
y_train= encoder.transform(y_train)  
y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)
```

I got the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-45c4512ecc1f> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
      2 encoder = LabelBinarizer()
----> 3 encoder.fit(y_train + y_test)
      4 y_train= encoder.transform(y_train)
      5 y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S5') dtype('S5') dtype('S5')
```

**EDIT3:**
My code from jupyter :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras
import numpy as  np
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 66
epochs = 12

data_pixels=np.genfromtxt("pixels_dataset.csv", delimiter=',')

classes_dataset=np.genfromtxt("labels.csv",dtype=np.str , delimiter='\t')

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_pixels, classes_dataset, test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(y_train + y_test)
y_train= encoder.transform(y_train)  
y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)
```

Comment: You need to `transform` your `y_test` using `encoder` fitted on your train data. So you need to change your code to: `y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)`

Comment: As @MarcinMożejko said, `fit()` or `fit_transform()` should only be called on training data. On test data only `transform()` should be called.

Comment: @VivekKumar, please the update l got new error

Comment: `y_train` and `y_test` are numpy arrays. Dont use `+` between them like this. Infact move your `encoder.fit()` above the `train_test_split`. Call it on `classes_dataset` like this:  `classes_dataset =  encoder.fit_transform(classes_dataset)`. Then no need to call it on `y_train` and `y_test`.

Comment: What's wrong when we use + between them ?

Comment: Because they are not lists. Arrays can be multi-dimensional, so on which dimension you want to add is not defined in this case. Example, in a 2d array, you want to append horizontally or vertically is ambigous in +

Comment: @VivekKumar, you're totally right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `transform` your `y_test` using `encoder` fitted on your train data. So you need to change your code to:

```
 y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)
```

Otherwise your `encoder` would be refitted what causes a problem.

**edit:**

You may also try:

```
encoder.fit(y_train + y_test) # in case of lists
encoder.fit(numpy.append(y_train, y_test)) # in case of numpy arrays
y_train= encoder.transform(y_train)  
y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)
```

**edit 2:**

What finally succeed to work was:

```
encoder.fit(numpy.append(y_train, y_test)) # in case of numpy arrays
y_train= encoder.fit_transform(y_train)  
y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)
```

Comment: You mean  : y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train) and   y_test= encoder.transform(y_test) ?

Comment: after doing this. l got the following error:
    496     if y_type in ("binary", "multiclass"):

ValueError: classes [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65] missmatch with the labels [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60]found in the data

Comment: Yes :) Only this second line should be changed.

Comment: see my update, l got the following error : TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S5') dtype('S5') dtype('S5')

Comment: Are you running this from `jupyter` notebook? Is your `data` stored as `numpy` arrays?

Comment: yes in jupyter. my data are csv files loaded using numpy genfromtxt. see my update please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139882/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-vincent).

Comment: @MarcinMożejko why the fit_transform() again on y_train after fit() on combined data in your edit2??

Comment: It's because this was the version which finally worked on OP machine. I don't know why - but this is an exact code snippet which solved a problem - so we add it to answer.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Then no need to call `encoder.fit(numpy.append(y_train, y_test))`

Comment: Actually - I thought the same but OP said that this didn't work in his case.